# How to find why call is not connecting

Tags: calls, connection-issues

My mobile phone is not able to make calls. All calls are ending after 4-5 seconds. All the settings seem to be fine. Is there any log file where sim provider logs some reason? Or any other way to find the reason for the issue?

Comment: Which Android phone and Android version are you using? Which network provider is it? Did you try using an another SIM and using your SIM in an another phone?

Comment: My first thought would be along Firelord's lines as well, assuming you have rebooted, and performed rudimentary troubleshooting. The next step is to find a friend or go to the carrier store and try a SIM swap, put your SIM in a known working phone and a known working SIM in yours. If the problem stays with the SIM, get a new one, If the problems continue, it is time to get the carrier involved to check your account configuration. If the problem stays with the phone perform a Network Settings Reset (if your device is new enough), otherwise perform a factory reset.